# How to copy two Git repository in same folder

Tags: git

I have:

```
Project A   and  Project B
Folder A          Folder C 
Folder A-1        Folder D
File1.txt         File21.txt
                  File22.txt
```

which are git repositories and want to copy their contents through GIT clone in same folder so final structure will have

```
Folder A
Folder A-1
Folder C
Folder D
File1.txt 
File21.txt 
File22.txt
```

I tried through repo manifest and git submodules but both failed to achieve.

Through manifest when i try this, i get error message

```
fatal: duplicate path . in /home/Workspace/   .repo/manifests/Manifest-Trial.xml
```

Manifest File

```
<project path="." name="Trial/Project A" remote="XYZ" revision="master"/>
<project path="." name="Trial/Project B" remote="XYZ" revision="master"/>
```

If i configure Project B as submodule in Project A

```
git submodule add -b master ssh://gitprogit/Project B Trunk
```

It copies all contents under folder Project A/Trunk instead of Project A.
Even if we dont specify folder during submodule addition it will copy it under Proect B?

Any pointers will really help.

Comment: You want to merge both repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we need to maintain the multiple applications in a same git dir we should be making use of git submodules.

Please check the http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules.